# Read .sql script with parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameter-passing

I have a .sql script that contain the following code

```sql
-- Drop stored procedure if it already exists
USE Temp

IF EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
   WHERE SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = N'Custom'
     AND SPECIFIC_NAME = N'RestoreVersion' 
)
   DROP PROCEDURE Custom.RestoreVersion
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Custom.RestoreVersion
    @ID INT
AS
    SELECT * FROM [App].[Version] WHERE ID = @ID
    DROP PROCEDURE Custom.RestoreVersion
GO

EXECUTE Custom.RestoreVersion @ID = [ID from c# program]
GO
```

I would like to take this file and set the @ID parameter in c# and then run the sql script.

I want this script to live in a folder on my application but I can't get it to work.

I tried this.

```
Console.Write(Server_Name + Environment.NewLine);
connectSqlServer(Server_Name);

SqlDataReader rdr = null;

Console.WriteLine("\nGet Version\n");
try
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Custom.RestoreVersion", conn);

    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", ID));

    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Values);
    }
}
finally
{
    if (conn != null)
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    if (rdr != null)
    {
        rdr.Close();
    }
}
```

However I am unable to get this to read the file from the Resources folder and enter the parameters to the database.

Comment: Procedure to delete itself? and what error are you getting

Comment: There is nothing in the code that would read from a file, so it's not surprising that it doesn't. Why do you think that it would?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Also the script only _creates_ the stored procedure, it doesn't run it and therefore does not need the parameter to have a value. I don't see how the two sides are meant to match up

Comment: Yes the proc deletes itself as we don't want to leave the procedure on the server at the end this is obviously a small snippit of the full proc. 

I have edited the question turns out the copy and past didn't work properly so missed it out. I run it at the end. 

@Guffa sorry my question was how would I make it read from file as whenever I try and read from file I can only read to string or would you read to string and then do a replace in string?

thanks duely noted.

Comment: Why would you want to create a procedure just to execute it and then remove it? Why not just execute a query?

Comment: @Nim why would you use a proc *at all* then? just use a parameterized command (not a sproc)

Comment: @MarcGravell So as far as I was aware you could only parameterize a command if it's all writen in c# however if the entire query is 50 lines it makes it hard to change so this is how I did it originally but then wanted to have it so it would just read a query in a .sql file and then change the paramters accordingly but couldn't work out how to do that but did know how to pass paramaters to a stored procedure.

Comment: @Nim k, I think I understand; I'll edit my answer a bit... one moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no purpose whatsoever in creating a proc that deletes itself just to parameterize something; you can do that directly:

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT * FROM [App].[Version] WHERE ID = @ID", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", ID));
    using(var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            var id = rdr.GetInt32(0);
            var name = rdr.GetString(1);
            // etc
        }
    }
}
```

or with a tool like dapper:

```
foreach(var row in conn.Query("SELECT * FROM [App].[Version] WHERE ID = @ID",
       new { ID })
{
    int id = row.Id;
    string name = row.Name
    // etc
}
```

---

From comments, it sounds like the problem is larger queries; there are several ways of doing that; the simplest is *just code it in C# anyway*, for example:

```
var sql = @"
-- this is a long query
declare @foo table(id int not null)
insert @foo (id)
select RangeId
from SomeTable
where Category = @category

select ... /* blah blah

lots more blah */";

cmd.CommandText = sql;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("category", whatever);
// ...
```

Or alternatively, if you really want the query to be separate:

```
cmd.CommandText = ReadQueryFromResources("myquery");
```